# fopen failed to open stream: No space left on device in /home/

Tags: php, linux, centos

I get this error "failed to open stream: No space left on device in /home/..." when I try to copy to one of the directory. The error comes only for one of the directories. I have tried other directories and there it works fine.
Also df -i etc shows enough free nodes. I do have enough free disk space on device. My disk quota is unlimited. Anybody can help?

Comment: You should check your disk quota. https://www.linuxtechi.com/enable-user-group-disk-quota-on-centos-7-rhel-7/

Comment: disk quota is unlimited. i have edited question with this addition. Also this is only for one of the directories. All other directories inside same user directories are fine.